# Displaying words after taking data (user chosen word length) from a txt file PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am a bit new to PHP and have a question that I would like to get some different ideas on. I am writing a PHP script that will open as a html form with an intro section, a few radio buttons, and a submit button. When the user clicks submit, there is a static text file that I have chosen(ebook) that I want the PHP script to remove words from the file depending on the length in which the user chooses (radio buttons are labeled 1,2,3,etc).

This is what I have been playing with:

```
<?php
    $myTextFile = "ebook.txt";
    $fileContents = get_file_contents($myTextFile);
    $txtTok = strtok("allremoveddelimiters", $myTextFile);

    while ($txtTok != false){
    echo $txtTok;
    $myTok = strtok("allremoveddelimiters");
    }

?>
```

I have gotten my string stripped of all delimiters chosen, and it echoes out all on one line. This is where I have become stuck. What I am needing to do now is to pull words with a certain length (user chosen through radio buttons) out of the text file and then print the changed txt file to the screen. I have looked at the explode() function, but I am not sure that I really understand it. I also played with the str_replace() but it didn't seem to do what I needed it to, or I just didn't understand the complete function. Also, I was advised to not use the preg_() functions. I am assuming that I would want to take the txt file and put all the words in to an array and then pull the words of the user chosen length out and then print the updated array back as a string, but so far I haven't found an example that was understandable by my novice skills.

A push in any direction will be certainly appreciated. If any other information is needed, please advise.

Example: 
The full string would contain this -

> YOU don't know about me without you have read a book by the name of The
>   Adventures of Tom Sawyer; but that ain't no matter.  That book was made
>   by Mr. Mark Twain, and he told the truth, mainly.  There was things which
>   he stretched, but mainly he told the truth.  That is nothing.

And if the user chooses 3 from the choices -

> don't know about me without  have read a book by  name of Adventures of Sawyer; that ain't no matter.  That book made by Mr. Mark Twain, he told truth, mainly. There things which he stretched, mainly he told truth. That is nothing.

Comment: +1 for "*push in any direction*"

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Let's assume, for example, that your file consists of a single string: `I, like, do'x - some bi- magic` and I have chosen the '2' as the target length. How should the result string look like?

Comment: Can you add some content of `ebook.txt` and also add sample output with specific length

Comment: @raina77ow - In the sample string you gave 'I, like, do'x -some bi- magic' if the user were to click the "2" then I would want the script to remove do & bi to read 'I like x some magic'.

Comment: @ProgNewbie So you need to strip all the delimiters as well?

Comment: @raina77ow - Correct. I was going to do this as soon as the user made a selection. With it being a book, I will want to keep SOME of the punctuation, but there are a lot of delimiters that I don't need in the file which is why I wanted to strip it of them before stripping out the words. And thanks for your patience with me. Just trying to gain some knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about this quickly, I would recommend looking at regular expressions. This should easily allow you to extract words based on length. They can be quite complicated to understand though.

I would push you in the direction of preg_replace, http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php. This will allow you (once you have your working regular expression) to extract words of the specified length, and replace them with an empty string.

I would recommend looking at a site like http://public.kvalley.com/regex/regex.asp for testing created regular expressions.

Having taken a quick look, I believe the following expression matches 4 letter words:

```
\b(\w{4})\b
```

Replace the 4 in the string with the length of the word you want to match. To break down the Regex simply, \b stands for a word boundary (ie space, full stop), \w stands for a word character (letters or digits), and {4} means match the previous item 4 times (so a 4 letter word). I believe the following will work.

```
$myReplacedString = preg_replace('/\b(\w{4})\b/', '', $myString);
$myTrimmedString = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $myReplacedString));
```

where $myString is your string you've fetched from your file.

I hope this explains it well.

Comment: In fact, `\b(\w{4,})\b` will match words with 4 or _more_ letters. You have to use `\w{4}` to match strictly.